# C# Inheritance after double

Tags: c#

I would like to add some functions to double type. I created new class "ExtraDouble" and I I want to class behave as double.

For example: I have:

```
class ExtraDouble{
double myVar = 0.59;
}
```

And, wherever:

```
Extradouble e = new Extradouble();
String.Format("Value of e is: {0}", e) // return: Value of e is: 0.59
```

Is it possible?

Default using "e" must return value of variable "myVar" (without any accessors)

Comment: First off you'd probably be better off making it an immuteable struct.  But really you could just create extention methods on `double` instead.  FYI `String.Format` is going to call `ToString` so you just have to override that and return `myVar.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  All objects have a virtual `ToString` method.  For your case, just override that:

```
class ExtraDouble
{
    double myVar = 0.59;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myVar.ToString();
    }        
}
```

---

For more completeness.  If you want your `ExtraDouble` to behave as a double in common scenarios (like performing arithmetic operations), you can use the `implicit` keyword:

```
class ExtraDouble : Object
{
    double myVar = 0.59;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myVar.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator double(ExtraDouble d)
    {
        return d.myVar;
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
Console.WriteLine(5 * new ExtraDouble());
```

Comment: Ok. But if I want to use - for example:  e * e, I must override others method, yes? There isn't any unviersal method?

Comment: pretty sure my answer covers your question as to how.  And no, converting to a string and implicitly converting to a double cannot be combined into a universal method

Comment: @mathemaniac00 If you do `ExtraDouble * ExtraDouble` and do not have `operator*` overloaded, the compiler will use the implicit operators, so it'll work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to class that behaves like a double but with extended functionality. You could take a look at object extensions. They are designed to extend classes that you do not normally have access to inherit.

```
public static class DoubleExtension
{
    public static double Sqr(this double d)
    {
        return d * d;
    }
}
```

This will make it look like the Sqr() is a method of the type double.
E.g.

```
double d = 2.0f;
double sqrD = d.Sqr(); 
// This value will now be 4. This call looks like a class method but its not, it's an extension
```